# How to broadcast text via Bluetooth like a HID keyboard?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth, hid

My client needs an app where he can input the text data and send it to another android device via Bluetooth. On the receiving device, the text should be inputted into currently active text field (doesn’t matter if it’s in settings, browser or any other app). My idea of this is to broadcast the text as HID so it behaves like an external Bluetooth keyboard. Is it possible to create such app?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the length of your string. There is no such thing as broadcast in Bluetooth, but there is device advertisement. Each device can advertise its services, and every other device can listen to that.

But the advertisement payload is limited to 37 bytes. And for your purpose, you'd need a proprietary service UUID, which takes 16 bytes from that. That leaves you 21 bytes to work with. If you are OK with that, you can set the string that you want to broadcast as the name of the device in the advertisement payload.

Comment: On second thought. Broadcasting is not really a good idea. What would serve you better is to make the sender a GATT server, which advertises and exposes a proprietary GATT service you define. This service has a characteristic that stores the live string data. The receiver works as a GATT client. It scans for the GATT server with your service, and then subscribe to the characteristic, whose value gets updated with the keyboard input. Google has extensive documentation and examples here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le

Comment: And more samples at their github repos: https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples